# How to pass arguments when i profile a CLI PHP in Zend Studio?

Tags: php, profiling, zend-studio, zend-debugger

I would like to profile a php script in CLI mode with Zend Studio 11.0.
When I click right on the script, i choose "profile as" > "1 PHP CLI application". The script is immediately executed and profiled. But I have to pass arguments to the script. How to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is : we have to add a new profile configuration (click right on the script > Profile as > Profile configurations ...), and add the arguments on the section "PHP script arguments".
Then, run the new configuration which is in the menu of the profile button.